# How to convert Option<Option<String>> to Option<Option<&str>> in Rust?

Tags: rust, option-type

I am trying to make this conversion (`Option<Option<String>>` to `Option<Option<&str>>`) possible, but I still failed after trying many methods including using `.map`.

I know that the conversion is possible, however, if there's no nested `Option` (i.e. `Option<String>` to `Option<&str>`): just using `.as_deref()`.
Using `.map(|inner| inner.as_deref())` violates the ownership.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason using a plain `map` violates ownership rules is because it takes `self`.  You're consuming the outer `Option` and then trying to borrow something from inside it, which doesn't work.

However, there's an easy approach here, using `as_ref` and then `as_deref` inside the `map`.  `as_ref` turns `&Option<T>` into `Option<&T>`, where `T` is `Option<String>`, so when you call `map`, you get an `&Option<String>`, which you can then safely pass to `as_deref`.

```
fn main() {
    let foo = Some(Some(String::from("abc")));
    let bar: Option<Option<&str>> = foo.as_ref().map(|r| r.as_deref());
    eprintln!("{:?}", bar);
}
```

Comment: That is a neat solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you find yourself stringing together multiple methods and closures to work with `Option`, `Result`, or even things like `hash_map::Entry`, *consider* going back to basics and using a `match`:

```rust
pub fn opt_opt_str_ref(input: &Option<Option<String>>) -> Option<Option<&str>> {
    match input {
        Some(Some(s)) => Some(Some(s.as_str())),
        Some(None) => Some(None),
        None => None,
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that when read, its meaning is obvious; there is no question about what it actually does. If it needs to be changed to do something slightly different, how to do so is obvious.

It's not always better (and this particular example is particularly inelegant with all the repetition), but (in my opinion) it's always worth considering the option.